# How OpenXmlReader.Skip supposed to work?

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, xlsx, xmlreader

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.skip(v=office.15).aspx#):

> Skips the **child elements** of the current node.

Here is code:

```
var reader = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);

// Header
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.ElementType == typeof (Row)) // reader is at row r="1"
    {
        headers = GetHeaders((Row)reader.LoadCurrentElement(), _doc.WorkbookPart);
        reader.ReadNextSibling(); // reader is at row r="2"
        break;
    }
}

//...
reader.Skip(); // reader is at row r="3"
```

Worksheet xml (cut):

```
<x:sheetData xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:row r="1" spans="1:1">
      <x:c r="A1" s="1" t="s">
        <x:v>36</x:v>
      </x:c>
  </x:row>
  <x:row r="2" spans="1:1"> <!-- before calling Skip reader is here -->
      <x:c r="A2" s="1" t="s">
        <x:v>38</x:v>
      </x:c>
  </x:row> <!-- I expect reader to be here after calling Skip because closing tag != child element -->
  <x:row r="3" spans="1:1"> <!-- after calling Skip reader goes here -->
      <x:c r="A3" s="1" t="s">
        <x:v>38</x:v>
      </x:c>
  </x:row>
</x:sheetData>
```

Why `Skip` skips also `</x:row>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<x:row>` is the start tag (marks the beginning) and `</x:row>` is the end tag (marks the end) of **one** element in a XML file.

When you have parsed the XML document it is represented as tree of node objects, each node having parents, siblings and children.

So don't confound the representation as tree in memory with the representation as file.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but anyway I think it is wrong or at least confusing and documentation needs to be updated. For example `OpenXmlReader.Read` (Moves to read the next element as per doc) it also reads *end tags* from that I can make a conclusion that end tag treated as a separate element which should not be skipped because it is not child, also OpenXmlReader.LoadCurrentElement moves reader to end tag. I think Skip should be consistent and it should leave reader at end tag for consistency. Do you disagree?

Comment: @Vladimir yes it can be confusing. Javas `XMLStreamReader` for example positions on the start tag and end tag, i.e. treats them as separate positions, whereas `OpenXMLReader` operates on elements and not on tags

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small extension method to skip until the next tag of an element of type T. The tag can be an opening or a closing tag.
(Attention: if there is no tag of that type left then it will skip to the end of the document)

```
public static void SkipTo<T>(this OpenXmlReader reader) where T : OpenXmlElement
{
    while (reader.Read() && reader.ElementType != typeof(T))
        ;
}
```

So normally while reading you know the type of your current element:

```
if (reader.ElementType == typeof(PivotFields) && !reader.IsEndElement)
{
    // some code ...
    reader.SkipTo<PivotFields>(); // reader is now at </x:pivotFields>
    // some code ...
}
```